# Can AWS Kinesis be used for more than one type of message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I have a Kinesis stream in my setup and currently have one type of message that I put on it. The current message, at the end of the day, ends up in a datastore.

Now I need to publish a new message type. Is it the best practice to continue and use the same Kinesis stream or is it easiest to have a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a single stream to send different messages, however when you have so, your consumer needs to customize the logic for different message types

It may not work when you would want to integrate kinesis with Kinesis firehose or analytics since firehose or analytics may need a single format for processing from a single stream